# gxThread - shed_yield equivalent

Tags: c++, multitasking, yield

Is it possible to yield the processor using gxThread functions, like the POSIX call [shed_yield](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_yield) does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found nothing like that in [the gxThread documentation](http://www.datareel.com/docs/classes/thread/gxthread.htm), however their [thread model diagram](http://www.datareel.com/docs/classes/thread/tdiagram.htm) indicates that they use native threads underneath. So if you cannot replace gxThread with another threading library, I would recommend to just use platform-dependent calls such as `sched_yield` or `SwitchToThread`.